# The angle of rotation of the object is wrong

Tags: java, swing, game-physics

I'm trying to rotate an object in java but i noticed that something is wrong.
When i rotate it of 180 degrees,i get a value of the angle of '90°',so in order to get an angle of 360 degrees i have to rotate it twice.
What's wrong?
[0°,90°,180°](https://postimg.org/gallery/2r76pnlb0/)

The code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


    if (rotate == true) {
        ship.increaseDegress();
    }

    ship.draw(g);

}
```

Ship.java

```
public void increaseDegress() {
    rotationAngle += 10;
    if(rotationAngle>360) {
        rotationAngle = 0;
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    this.g = g;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    Rectangle rect = this.getBounds();
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.draw(at.createTransformedShape(this));

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The answer will depend on where you think 0 points

Comment: And you seem to be applying the rotation twice, and without further information, repeatedly (every time it paints, you're rotating the whole graphics context by the angle again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's take a quick look at your code...

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    this.g = g;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    Rectangle rect = this.getBounds();
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.draw(at.createTransformedShape(this));

}
```

So,

- First you create `AffineTransform`, nice
- You rotate the transformer, also nice
- You apply the transformer to the `Graphics` context ... okay, there's a problem here, but let's move on
- You apply the transformer to the shape!

So, on a single draw pass, you will rotate the shape by `rotationAngle * 2`!  So, when the angle is 10°, the shape will be rendered at 20°, when it's 20°, it will rendered at 40°!

Okay, but there's another problem.  Transformations applied to a `Graphics` context are compounding, this means, based on the available code, each time you call `draw`, the `Graphics` context is been rotated by `rotationAngle`.  So if `rotationAngle` is 10°

- On pass #1, the shape will be rotated to 20°
- On pass #2, the shape will be rotated to 30°
- On pass #3, the shape will be rotated to 40°
- ... so on and so forth ...

So, what's the answer?

When ever I pass a `Graphics` context off to some other method, I first create a copy it, because I don't trust anybody!

```
Graphics gCopy = g.create();
shape.draw(gCopy);
gCopy.dispose();
```

This ensures that the state of the `Graphics` context is returned to the state it was before I called `draw`, that will get rid of the compounding transformation.

The other solution is, don't transform the `Graphics` context.  If you're transforming the shape, what's the point?

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    this.g = g;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    Rectangle rect = this.getBounds();
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.draw(at.createTransformedShape(this));

}
```